# ng storage of list at angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a problem that i want to local storage a list and load it but
i found two problems that removing the item does not work well
and local storage is not working

```
.controller('tasksCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  '$stateParams',
  '$localStorage',
  function($scope, $stateParams) {
    var dirlist = this;
    var tasks = [
      {
        name: 'add task',
        time: '12',
        type: 'test'
      }, {
        name: 'do the home work',
        time: '11',
        type: 'study'
      }
    ];
    dirlist.list = tasks;
    dirlist.toggle = false;
    dirlist.addtask = function() {
      dirlist.list.push({name: dirlist.name, time: dirlist.time, type: dirlist.type});
      dirlist.name = '';
      dirlist.time = '';
};
dirlist.remove = function(item) {
  dirllist.splice(dirlist.list.indexOf(item), 1)
};

dirlist.saveData = function() {
  $localStorage.list = tasks;
}
dirlist.loadData = function() {
  dirlist.list = $localStorage.list;
}



 }
])
```

Comment: can you create a plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> local storage is not working

This is because you haven't passed the dependency in your controller.
You are passing only `scope` and `stateParams`.

Here's how you can fix it,

```
.controller('tasksCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  '$stateParams',
  '$localStorage',
  function($scope, $stateParams, $localStorage) {
```

Now, `$localStorage` can be used as `localStorage` service.

Hope it helps.

Cheers coding!